# How to delete a object in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. Here i want to delete a object from database but it is not working. Why this happend?
is there something wrong?

```
@foreach ($todo as $item)
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 2px solid black;">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td style="border: 2px solid black;">{{ $item->todo }}</td>
            <form action="">
                @csrf
                <td style="border: 2px solid black;"><button style="background-color: green;" type="submit">Selesai</button></td>
            </form>
            <form action="">
                @csrf
                <td style="border: 2px solid black;"><button style="background-color: yellow;" type="submit">Ubah</button></td>
            </form>
            <form action="{{ route('todo.destroy', $item) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('delete')
                <td style="border: 2px solid black;"><button style="background-color: red;" type="submit">Hapus</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'todo' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ]);

    Todo::create($validated);
    return redirect(route('todo.index'));
}
public function destroy(ToDo $toDo)
{
    $toDo->delete();
    return redirect(route('todo.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

update the form to pass the `id` of the model you want to delete.

```html
<form action="{{ route('todo.destroy', $item->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('delete')
  <td style="border: 2px solid black;">
    <button style="background-color: red;" type="submit">Hapus</button>
  </td>
</form>
```

in your controller's delete you can call `dd($toDo)` to check if the model is the one you expect.

Comment: this is the only correct anwser. For route model binding, you should always pass the id of your object, not the object itself

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the object is valid, I think you need put the id and then delete by id. Example:

```
$toDo = ToDo::find($id);
$toDo->delete();
```

Comment: i tried it. but error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist.

Comment: i can create a new object, just can't delete it

Comment: Try this: $toDo->each->delete();

Comment: Or try this Todo::find($id)->first();

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to delete it from a collection, but i think you want to delete it with the builder function. Please make sure you are handeling the call on the correct object.

For collections you could use the function forget `$toDo->forget();`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your object isn't being [**soft-deleted**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#soft-deleting)? Check the ToDo table if you have a `deleted_at` column and if yes, check that it contains a date for the items you deleted already.

If this is the case, then decide:

1. if you want to keep soft-deletes, then you need to read the list of todos with `->withoutTrashed()` method.
2. if you don't want soft-deletes, remove the `deleted_at` column (probably with a migration) and also the `SoftDeletes` trait from your model.

---

On a side note, it's ok to ask for help on StackOverflow, but this topic is also a good reason for you to dig a bit inside laravel and setting up a [debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrQWtbxY1Hs) to learn more about PHP/laravel. I recommend doing that first.